# USB Hierarchy Driver

Tags: windows, macos, usb

Is it possible to create a driver (windows/mac) for a custom usb hub such that it appears as one device in My Computer / Finder and the attached usb card readers each show up as a sub-folder within that device? Any pointers to the right direction to look at would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is *possible*, but unholy amounts of difficult. You really don't want to do this. Really. You'll basically be reimplementing USBHub.sys from scratch, as well as breaking the standard paradigm of drives in Windows (i.e. drives appear in My Computer).

Answer (score 0):

You have two routes to doing this:

1) Build your own custom USB hub device, which presents itself as a single drive, and creates its own internal folders based on the devices attached.

2) Write some seriously ninja driver code combining multiple USB card-reader devices into a single drive. This would be extremely platform dependent (Windows v. Mac), and would require what would be at least 6 months of work, give or take.

I honestly would go with the first if it's a big must. Would take a custom piece of hardware though...